# How to combine multiple SELECT statements in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Could somebody tell me how I would more efficiently write the following collection of SELECT statements:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM brand WHERE 
name NOT LIKE '' OR
name = 'Hot Brands'
ORDER BY name ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($brand=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

?>

<?

$bid = $brand['brand_id'];
$sql2="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
$total = mysql_num_rows($result2); 

$bawtrysql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Bawtry' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$bawtryresult=mysql_query($bawtrysql);
$bawtrytotal = mysql_num_rows($bawtryresult); 

$chainsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Chain' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$chainresult=mysql_query($chainsql);
$chaintotal = mysql_num_rows($chainresult); 

$granthamsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Grantham' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$granthamresult=mysql_query($granthamsql);
$granthamtotal = mysql_num_rows($granthamresult); 

$internetsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Internet' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$internetresult=mysql_query($internetsql);
$internettotal = mysql_num_rows($internetresult); 

$bmsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND title = 'Mens' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Bawtry' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$bmresult=mysql_query($bmsql);
$bm = mysql_num_rows($bmresult); 

$blsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND title = 'Ladies' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Bawtry' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$blresult=mysql_query($blsql);
$bl = mysql_num_rows($blresult); 

$cmsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND title = 'Mens' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Chain' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$cmresult=mysql_query($cmsql);
$cm = mysql_num_rows($cmresult); 

$clsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND title = 'Ladies' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Chain' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$clresult=mysql_query($clsql);
$cl = mysql_num_rows($clresult); 

$gmsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND title = 'Mens' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Grantham' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$gmresult=mysql_query($gmsql);
$gm = mysql_num_rows($gmresult); 

$glsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND title = 'Ladies' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Grantham' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$glresult=mysql_query($glsql);
$gl = mysql_num_rows($glresult); 

$imsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND title = 'Mens' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Internet' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$imresult=mysql_query($imsql);
$im = mysql_num_rows($imresult); 

$ilsql="SELECT * FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND title = 'Ladies' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_location = 'Internet' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$ilresult=mysql_query($ilsql);
$il = mysql_num_rows($ilresult); 

$query = "SELECT SUM(shop_order_price) FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'";
$result3 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
    ?>

    <?
    $showtotal = $row3['SUM(shop_order_price)'] ;
    $showaverage = $row3['SUM(shop_order_price)'] / $total ;
    ?>

            <tr>
                <td align="center"><strong><?=$brand['name'];?></strong></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$bm?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$bl?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$bawtrytotal?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$cm?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$cl?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$chaintotal?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$gm?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$gl?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$granthamtotal?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$im?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$il?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$internettotal?></td>
                <td align="center"><strong><?=$total?></strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong><?=round($showtotal, 2)?></strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong><?=round($showaverage, 2)?></strong></td>
            </tr>
```

Each SELECT statement extracts the number of rows matching a query based on location and gender. The number of matching rows is eventually echoed out at the bottom into an HTML. table.

In the interest of efficiency - I wonder whether all of these statements could be combined to reduce the number of calls to the database.

I apologise for the mess - this isn't my code! I've come to this project recently.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

*** UPDATE ***

Ok so here's my new SELECT statement :

```
SELECT * FROM shop_orders
LEFT JOIN product
ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id=product.product_id
WHERE 
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."' AND shop_order_location = 'Bawtry' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND shop_order_location = 'Chain' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' 

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND shop_order_location = 'Grantham'  AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' 

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND shop_order_location = 'Internet'  AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' 

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND category = 'Mens'  AND shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'  AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' 

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND category = 'Ladies' AND shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'  AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' 

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND category = 'Mens'   AND shop_order_location = 'Chain'  AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' 

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND category = 'Ladies'   AND shop_order_location = 'Chain'  AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' 

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND category = 'Mens'   AND shop_order_location = 'Grantham'  AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' 

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND category = 'Ladies'   AND shop_order_location = 'Grantham'  AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' 

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND category = 'Mens'   AND shop_order_location = 'Internet'  AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' 

OR
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
AND category = 'Ladies'   AND shop_order_location = 'Internet'  AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'" ;
```

My new question is how would I draw out the individual figures for each of the OR variations within the statement and echo these out into the HTML table?

Thanks

Comment: use `union` to combine it

Comment: `select count()` is more efficient than `select *` and then get the number with `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel you don't have to do a second fetch, just one, you can get rid of `mysql_num_rows()`

Comment: Yeah, I missed that (and thus deleted my comment), I didn't realize that OP is only looking for the count, not for the fetched rows themselves.

Comment: @Aphex22 I deleted my answer as it was confusing and misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine the `SELECT`s as each one is fetching a certain amount that - if you combine them - simply return a sum of all queries.

But instead of fetching all elements and the fetching the `mysql_num_rows()` you could change your queries like this:

```
$sql2="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop_orders WHERE  brand = '".$bid."' AND shop_order_month = '".$m."' AND shop_order_year = '".$y."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' ";
$total = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql2));
```

You don't need all elements of the row (`SELECT *`) but you just seem to need the number of affected elements. So `COUNT(*)` is your choice!

Comment: Thanks Gottlieb - So would I need to use COUNT(*) for each separate instance of OR in my updated SELECT statement above? Or could I combine the SELECT statements using COUNT(*) ?

Comment: No, you will still need as many `SELECT` queries as you have `mysql_num_row()` calls (13 if I didn't miscount). But instead of `SELCET *` you query `SELECT COUNT(*)`. And you don't call `mysql_num_rows()` but `mysql_fetch_array()`, that will already contain the number of rows, because of `COUNT(*)`. So it's kind of streamlined, whereas not significantly fewer lines of code.